# Узнать, какое число больше

Tags: python, if

Нужно ввести два числа и программа должна написать, какое из чисел больше:

```
a = int(input("Введите a : ")) # Вводим число a
b = int(input("Введите b : ")) # Вводим число b
c = not(a < b) # Переменная c показывает результат Trve или False
print(c) # Вывод c
    if c == True # На этом фрагменте кода возникает ошибка
    print("a больше, чем b")
        else:
        print("b больше, чем a" )
```

Не работает... Где я ошибся?

Comment: и в чем заключается вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a, b = int(input()), int(input())
print(a if a > b else b)
```

Comment: Не мог бы ты объяснить где я ошибся?

Comment: @Sman В форматировании и в, том, что спешишь в изучении. Этот код усложнен и написан неправильно...

Comment: А если `a==b` ?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru А если а==b, то можно написать любое из них т.к. они равны :ok_hand:

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, :) вопрос не так стоит.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Ну тогда это будет... undefined behavior ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
a = int(input("Введите a : ")) # Вводим число a
b = int(input("Введите b : ")) # Вводим число b

if a > b:
    print("a больше, чем b")
elif a < b:
    print("b больше, чем a")
else:
    print("a равно b")
```

Если через булевые:

```
c = a > b
if c:
    print("a больше, чем b")
else:
    print("a меньше или равно b")
```

Comment: Ну или так... ;)